# How to include remote machine "y.launch" and run it from local "x.launch"?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cannot launch remote machine "launch" file from local machine. Is there a way to accomplish that?

```
<launch>
  <machine name="machine_y" address="192.168.1.130" env-loader="/opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh"/>
  <include file="/path/to/remote/y.launch" machine="machine_y"/> <!-- doesn't work -->
  <node pkg="package_y" name="package_y_name" machine="machine_y"/> <!-- works -->
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274807/how-to-include-remote-machine-%22y.launch%22-and-run-it-from-local-%22x.launch%22?/) by [Ugnius Malukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30576/ugnius-malukas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if it's somehow possible using only `launch` files but it should be possible with bash scripts and ssh. Assuming we have `local_bash.sh`, `remote_bash.sh` scripts with `local.launch` and `remote.launch` launch files. To run `local.launch` on local and at the same time `remote.launch` on remote machine I would do something like this.

**local_bash.sh:**

```
roslaunch ros_package local.launch
ssh user@hostname 'bash -s' < remote_bash.sh
```

This will run `remote_bash.sh` script on your local host.

**remote_bash.sh** would then look like this:

```
roslaunch ros_package remote.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugnius Malukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30576/ugnius-malukas/) on 2017-11-03**:
I thought that there is a way by using only launches. Thanks, though.